# Timer Elapsed Event not hitting targeted method

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I am developing Windows service, in `OnStart()` method I am using `Timer` to hit `timer1_Tick` after a certain interval, but `timer1_Tick` not calling even once.

This is my code

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    var timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 30000; //every 30 secs
    timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    WriteToFile("Service has started..");
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteToFile("Entered in GetFailedProductDetails...");
    //code  
}
```

Starting code of widows service `Program.cs` file

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Service1 myService = new Service1();
        //myService.OnDebug();           
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer might be collected by the garbage collection, because you don't keep  a reference to it.

You should store it in a field:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer1;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 30000; //every 30 secs
    timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    WriteToFile("Service has started..");
}
```